# setTimeout not firing within expected time - but only in the context of the full test suite

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

The following test, when run alone, passes, as one would expect:

it('is not a crazy world', done =>
setTimeout(done, 100)
);

When run as part of a larger test suite though - this is timing out, after 2000 msec. Anybody have any idea what could be going on? All I can think of is that some other test is messing with the clock, but I'm not sure how to even start looking into that.

Comment: It is difficult to say precisely but know that `setTimeout`s aren't really guaranteed to timeout on schedule and in rare cases they might never timeout at all!. It all depends on the event loop I would suspect you have some CPU bound heavy lifting going on there

Comment: OK, got it - this was due to another test case calling `sinon.useFakeTimers()` without a corresponding `restore`. Thanks all.